# Markov Chains in a Casino

Tags: markov-chains

Consider an agent that enters a casino with an integer amount of money $y$
such that $0 < y \leq 5.$ The agent will stop gambling if the agent has
either 0 dollars (in which case, the agent cannot play) or 5 dollars. When
the agent has 1 or 2 dollars, the agent will bet the entire amount of money
that the agent has. If the agent has 3 or 4 dollars, the agent will bet the
difference between 5 dollars and the amount the agent currently has (i.e.
if the agent has 3 dollars, the agent will bet $5-3=2$ dollars). In each
gamble, there is a probability $p$ of winning the bet (and earning the bet)
and a probability $1-p$ of losing the bet (and losing that given amount of
money). \
It is apparent that we can express this as a Markov Chain, where each state
is the given dollar amount the agent has. Could someone help me with
classifying the states (i.e. absorbent, periodic, transient, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0 and 5 are absorbing states. Once entered, the process stays there.

For states 1,2,3,4, there is some probability you will immediately win enough bets in a row to get to 5 or lose enough to get to 0 (the absorbing states). Since, for which ever one of these states you start at, there is a non-zero probability of never returning, the states are transient.

Periodicity is a more difficult matter.

For instance, how can we get from state 1 back to state 1? There is only one way. You have to go from 1 to 2 to 4 to 3 back to 1. This is the only way. It is periodic with period 4.

To get from state 2 back to state 2 you can only go from 2 to 4 to 3 to 1 to 2. Period 4.

To get from state 3 back to state 3 you can only go from 3 to 1 to 2 to 4 to 3. Period 4.

Finally (you guessed it). For state 4 you can only go from 4 to 3 to 1 to 2 to 4. Period 4.